# Monitoring what goals are invoked by m2e while building project

Tags: eclipse, debugging, m2eclipse

After setting up lifecycle mapping Eclipse is invoking some of Maven goals (described in lifecycle mapping) as a part of build process. What I want to know is what exactly goals are actually invoked during project build.

I can see some of the Maven output at Eclipse console when I switch it to `Maven Console` mode but I still don't know whether goals that don't log anything (or don't log at high enough level) were invoked. I thought that maybe checking `Debug output` in Eclipse Maven settings might help but it didn't changed anything.

So question is how can I monitor what exactly goals (and from what plugins) are being invoked by m2e as a part of project build process.